# Embed patch file in sh file

Tags: patch

I'm trying to create a `.sh` file which internally runs a patch. So instead of running `patch -p0` of a patch file adjacent to the script, I'd like the patch to be embedded within.

I tried the below

```
patch -p0 <<EOF
Index: app/code/Magento/CustomerImportExport/Model/Import/Customer.php
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
--- app/code/Magento/CustomerImportExport/Model/Import/Customer.php     (date 1487543450000)
+++ app/code/Magento/CustomerImportExport/Model/Import/Customer.php     (revision )
@@ -371,6 +371,7 @@
         // attribute values
         foreach (array_intersect_key($rowData, $this->_attributes) as $attributeCode => $value) {
             if ($newCustomer && !strlen($value)) {
+                               $entityRow[$attributeCode] = $value;
                 continue;
             }

EOF
```

But it's not working. However when I run `patch -p0` on the original patch file, it works without any problems. Any clues what could be wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this suggestion from: [Re: [bug-patch] patch 2.6.1 with here document in a shell script](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-patch/2013-04/msg00001.html)

> Change the above to this, and it will work better:
>
> patch -p0 <<'EOF'
>
> Without the quotes, your script below expands constructs like $@ in the here script.

Comment: You sir, rock! :)